# How to change scenes in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) <= MaxDist)
    {
        //Call What Happens Here
    }
```

I want to replace the comment with some code that will send the player to the main menu (scene 0). This is JavaScript by the way, and I am using Unity 5.6. The full code is below.

```
    #pragma strict

    var Player : Transform;
    var MoveSpeed = 4;
    var MinDist = 3;
    var MaxDist = 20;

    function Start()
    {

    }

    function Update ()
    {
        transform.LookAt (Player);
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) >= MinDist)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;

            if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) <= MaxDist)
            {
                //Call What Happens Here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: javascript!=unityscript. They are different in syntax, features and in how they are evaluated. Unityscript is not ecma compliant. Tag should be changed. Here's some info about it: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SceneManager.LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) which can take either the build index or the name of the Scene

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) <= MaxDist)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

or

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) <= MaxDist)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName");
}
```

You just need to make sure to add all your scenes in your **Build Settings**.

Don't forget to import `SceneManagement` to be able to utilize it.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for: SceneManager. Here are the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html

```
#pragma strict
function Start() {
// Only specifying the sceneName or sceneBuildIndex will load the scene with the Single mode
SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName");
}
```